# Symfony2 how to disable default voter?

Tags: symfony

I have **five custom voters** in my application and use strategy "**consensus**".

Sometimes my voters not work properly and after debugging I have found the reason.

The standard Symfony RoleHierarchyVoter always returns "1", therefore sum of "**granted**" results **equals** to sum of "**deny**" results. So, I need to disable this Voter, because I don't use RoleHierarchy.

**1) How can I disable Voter in config?**

**2) Does it exist another solution for this issue?**

Thanks a lot for any help!

**UPDATED.**

So, I have created own RoleHierarchyVoter which always return false.
This Voter replace standard Voter, but I'm not sure this solution is true way.
Maybe any other solutions?

Comment: You could look into compiler passes http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html to remove the service completely.  Does seem like a strange default behavior though.

Comment: @Cerad tell me please, can be the reason of this issue that I have installed FOSUserBundle?

Comment: Don't know.  I have not implemented the consensus strategy.  I just know you can use a pass to modify service definitions.  And I stay far far away from FOSUserBundle.

Comment: I have added this as bug report https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16358

Comment: btw, currently impossible to remove definition of RoleHierarchyVoter, because it's registered with priority TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION and performed before my compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, currently I have solved the problem by creating **own RoleHierarchyVoter**, which always **return false**.

Currently impossible to remove definition of standard RoleHierarchyVoter, because it's registered with priority TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION and performed before my own compiler.

Btw, you can find in **SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php** next lines:

```
private function createRoleHierarchy($config, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!isset($config['role_hierarchy'])) {
            $container->removeDefinition('security.access.role_hierarchy_voter');

            return;
        }

        $container->setParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles', $config['role_hierarchy']);
        $container->removeDefinition('security.access.simple_role_voter');
    }
```

Even when I set `role_hierarchy: ~`, `isset($config['role_hierarchy']` will return true.

This issue has reported as bug https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16358

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of the `RoleVoter` says:

```
RoleVoter votes if any attribute starts with a given prefix.
```

The default prefix the `RoleVoter` will check is `ROLE_`, passed as default parameter value in the constuctor. These are required, because the voter has to check the current logged in user.

Make sure your own voters implements `VoterInterface` and also check the voter's implementation of `YourVoter::supportsClass`. The FQN of the element of which you want to know the user has access to should be checked over there. Then the following config should be enough:

```
app.security.download_voter:
    class:      AppBundle\Security\Voter\DownloadVoter
    public:     false
    tags:
        - { name: security.voter }
```

So:

1) You should not disable this voter, because all other voters rely on the `RoleHierarchy` this voter does create for the current user when passing a vote.

2) For better understanding of the `Voter` you can let the DIC inject the `logger` in your `voter`, and add extra info to the profiler. That way your own voters aren't a black box anymore.

Comment: thanks for answer, but this is something different from what I have asked. The reason, why I can't disable RoleHierarchyVoter I have described in my answer to this question.

Comment: Can you give me the link from where I can read that "all other voters rely on the RoleHierarchy..." ?

Comment: The `User` is a mandatory parameter of `is_granted`, that is the reason why the `RoleHierarchyVoter` should always be executed first. What do you pass as second argument to `is_granted`? It should be an entity that does implement `UserInterface`.

Comment: All what I passed to desideManager was correct. Btw, I have solved the problem few days ago, for this I had to explore sources of SecurityBundle. The problem was that when I set `role_hierarchy: ~` in security.yml, condition `isset($config['role_hierarchy'])` anyway returns true, even if it contains empty array. This is bug, I've reported it.